# Stellar.js Parallax Background with translate3d not working right in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, parallax, stellar.js

I am using a Wordpress theme which includes various JS libraries, including jQuery and the [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) plugin. In Firefox 49.0 the background images where the parallax effect is applied, appear with some kind of a wrong vertical offset and are generally buggy.

You can see the problem here: [select-salmon.gr](http://select-salmon.gr)

The problem disappears when I:

1. Resize the window (or)
2. Remove the `transform: translate3d` CSS property in the styles inspector (and thus reset the parallax effect)

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you possibly re-create the problem in a jsfiddle? I just checked and was able to "fix" the problem by removing the `top: 0px` of the `div.parallax-bg` rule in main.css. It seems strange to me that this rule had both `top: 0px;` and `bottom: 0px`. However, that "fix" does not apply with Google Chrome. A somewhat "hackish" solution would be to add a `window.resize();` script right before the end of your HTML `<body>` tag.

Comment: Just a note about the select-salmon site, scrolling is being overridden to a smooth crawl. Don't do that, it's terrible UX.